# getting current time of youtube videos while playing

Tags: javascript, html, youtube

When i play a Youtube video like this:

https://www.youtube.com/tv?#/watch/video/control?v=d1-VK12FZhs&resume&t=0m4s

i see the time playing and duration at bottom of video.

i can know current time playing looking for this in the page:

> < span class="ytp-time-current">0:11

After a little time this info is hidden until i pass again the mouse pointer over the video.

When the info is shown, i can get ytp-time-current value updated every second.
When the info is hidden, this value is not updated.
How to take the current time while the info is hidden?

I use this inside a chrome extension with this code:

```
document.addEventListener("spfdone", process); 
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", process); 

function process(){ 
stop(); 
start(); 
} 
window.onbeforeunload = function () { 
stop(); 
}; 

function start(){ 

x2 = setInterval(function() { 

// here is the place to use the solution i'm looking for

},1000); 
} 

function stop(){ 
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: how do you use that video? Do you embed it in an iframe or...?

Comment: i play it in chrome browser directly

Comment: so, you are looking for a way to get the time in the console with javascript?

Comment: yes. that is what i need

Comment: i have modified the url of the youtube video, as i use the tv format. Sorry for this late change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to YouTube iframe api you can use: [getCurrentTime()](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference).

It's enough to write in chrome console the following code:

```
document.querySelector('.video-stream').getCurrentTime()
```

Comment: i get this error: Uncaught TypeError: document.querySelector(...).getCurrentTime is not a function

Comment: The code needs to run into the page, not in the ext.  So, inject that code into the page and use events to pass back the values...

Comment: can be used in any way in the ext? i need to use on ext

Answer (score 0):

Here's a full solution for what you're looking to display:

```
var player = document.getElementById('movie_player');
var time = player.getCurrentTime();
var sec_num = parseInt(time, 10);
var hours   = Math.floor(sec_num / 3600);
var minutes = Math.floor((sec_num - (hours * 3600)) / 60);
var seconds = sec_num - (hours * 3600) - (minutes * 60);
if (hours < 10)
   hours = '0' + hours;
if (minutes < 10)
   minutes = '0' + minutes;
if (seconds < 10)
   seconds = '0' + seconds;
alert(hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds);
```

Comment: i get this error: Uncaught TypeError: player.getCurrentTime is not a function

Comment: How did you ran the code? You said you want to get the current time in JS console! I just tested it with both FireFox and Chrome consoles and both show an alert with the current time

Comment: I use the code in a chrome extension. I thought if that works on console should works also in the extension...

Comment: I see, the chrome extension would initialized before the page ready, could you test again with setTimeout after a few seconds

Comment: sorry, i don't understand what i need to do? currently i'm calling this every second. i think after some time the page must be loaded...

Comment: To avoid the error put the code inside: setTimeout(function(){ .......... }, 1000);  or it's better to create a function for this and replace the alert with whatever your label/text to set the value in

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183063/discussion-between-peterpam-and-wael101).